# Parsing JSON with python- list indices must be integer not str

Tags: python, json

I am beginner at python and am trying to parse the following JSON. I am not able to find out how to get the artist name and title of the song.

```
{
       "status": {
           "msg": "Success",
           "code": 0,
           "version": "1.0"
       },
       "metadata": {
           "music": [
               {
                   "external_ids": {
                       "isrc": "USSM10603618",
                       "upc": "888880170897"
                   },
                   "play_offset_ms": 8920,
                   "external_metadata": {
                       "spotify": {
                           "album": {
                               "id": "0JLv6iVbeiy4Dh2eIw6FKI"
                           },
                           "artists": [
                               {
                                   "id": "6vWDO969PvNqNYHIOW5v0m"
                               }
                           ],
                           "track": {
                               "id": "3qSMg1lhn4jDwWlI9xCVyK"
                           }
                       },
                       "itunes": {
                           "album": {
                               "id": 464320979
                           },
                           "artists": [
                               {
                                   "id": 1419227
                               }
                           ],
                           "track": {
                               "id": 464321089
                           }
                       },
                       "deezer": {
                           "album": {
                               "id": 72429
                           },
                           "artists": [
                               {
                                   "id": 145
                               }
                           ],
                           "genres": [
                               {
                                   "id": 132
                               }
                           ],
                           "track": {
                               "id": 551232
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   "title": "Listen (From the Motion Picture \"Dreamgirls\")",
                   "duration_ms": "217786",
                   "album": {
                       "name": "B'Day Deluxe Edition"
                   },
                   "acrid": "4660601066a3153acf15eabe2868572b",
                   "genres": [
                       {
                           "name": "Pop"
                       }
                   ],
                   "artists": [
                       {
                           "name": "Beyoncé"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "timestamp_utc": "2015-07-27 10:35:28"
       },
       "result_type": 0
}
```

My code is :

```
json_r=json.loads(res)
        print(json_r) 
        for i in json_r:
            song_name=json_r.metadata['music']['title']
            print song_name
            artist=json_r['metadata']['music']['artists']['name']
            s_t_id=json_r['metadata']['music']['external_metadata']['spotify']['track']['id']
            s_a_id=json_r['metadata']['music']['external_metadata']['spotify']['artists']['id']
```

I am getting the following error:
list indices must be integer not str

Please help

Comment: Do you see the square brackets in your JSON data? Those indicate `list`s, the indices of which must be integers.

Answer (score 1):

Their is a much more simpler way of doing this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('D:/data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

Try the above code this will print your file in terms of a dictionary.
Then you can simpley access it's element by using it's key indexes to
access it's value something like this :

```
print data['status']['msg']
print data['metadata']['music'][0]['album']['name']
```

Just make sure that which element you are trying to access, wether it's a list or dictionary, as in case of list `[]` you might need to use indexes , as explained in second example.

Answer (score 0):

See this data:

```
                       "artists": [
                           {
                               "id": "6vWDO969PvNqNYHIOW5v0m"
                           }
                       ],
                       "track": {
                           "id": "3qSMg1lhn4jDwWlI9xCVyK"
                       }
```

your "artists" data is a list, that's why you cannot access it like `["artists"]["id"]`, but `["artists"][0]["id"]` will work.

See below example for a clearer picture:

```
In [1]: a = [{"hello": "world"}, "yes I am"]

In [2]: a["hello"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-817deb35df57> in <module>()
----> 1 a["hello"]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

In [3]: a[0]
Out[3]: {'hello': 'world'}

In [4]: a[0]["hello"]
Out[4]: 'world'

In [5]: a[1]
Out[5]: 'yes I am'
```

Since "a" is a list, accessing its element can be done by index, ie. a[0], a[1]...

and `a[0]` is a dictionary `{"hello": "world"}`, so dictionary value can be accessed by first accessing its index 0, then the key "hello", as like `a[0]["hello"]`.